# How to list the exposed members of a package/dir-like method in Elm?

Tags: elm

I have been searching the official docs and existing questions and could not find any information on this - in Elm, how it would be possible to see the members/methods/variables that belong to or are exposed by a package in Elm, (such as the dir method in python), without having to dive into the source code each time?

What I want to do is get a simple list of what methods are exposed by an imported package. (So for a package like List, it should output `reverse` , `all`, `any`, `map`, etc.) I have attempted tab completion in `elm repl` and the elm extension available in VS code editor, and `elm repl` does not offer any methods such as `help`, `doc`, `?`, `dir`, `man`, etc., so I have no idea where to even start. I'm wondering how everyone else does this other than pulling up the source code for each and every package they use.

I apologize for the newbie question and if I misread or have been missing anything, but I couldn't even find anything in the https://elmprogramming.com tutorial. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question and having this functionality in repl is something I'd like to have also. I took a look at how Elmjutsu plugin for Atom does it and seems that it'll scans the source codes and downloads 3rd party module if needed. In python `dir` and `help` are sort of meta functions where they scan module source code. I haven't seen anything similar built-in in Elm yet.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing like this exists in Elm to do reflection over modules, unfortunately (as of 0.19.1, at least).

However, if you aren't looking to actually do this kind of thing at runtime, but rather as a convenient way of finding out for development, the elm packaging system enforces the requirement that all public functions are documented, so if you visit the package page, every public function and type will be documented there (obviously it can't enforce the content of the documentation, but at the very least it will be listed).